# Modes/States in Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing a game for android and I am trying to add the different game modes/states to it like in the lunar lander example. I am having problems with it because my activity starts from a title screen with a a few buttons and one you press to play the game. When you press the play button the app crashes. Is their anyway I can add the different modes/states to my game properly.

```
EDIT:

07-18 03:40:24.210: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.hitmanassault/com.android.hitmanassault.Hitman}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at com.android.hitmanassault.Hitman.onCreate(Hitman.java:48)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: You said that, "when you press the play button the app crashes."  Do you know how to view the stack trace for exceptions that happen in your app (logcat)?  Because that is the be-all-end-all for solving this sort of problem.

Comment: You are doing something in your thread which is throwing exception. Unless you post your code here. We cannot really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hitman.java, line 48

```
 ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView 07-18 03:40:24.391: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(224): at com.android.hitmanassault.Hitman.onCreate(Hitman.java:48) 07-18 03:40:24.391:
```

The object that you have created/retireved from the View hierarchy is probably not a TextView. Check your xml to know the correct type.

Comment: Thanks, lol I had my view id's labeled wrong inside of my view class.